# How to fix missing F on Java

Tags: java

I try to make a game Flappy Bird and want to test my result on DesktopLauncher, but something is happening that makes two errors. I can't find any F on the list.

```
package com.mygdx.flappy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;


public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration();

        config.width = 480; //this is the error part
        config.heigth = 800; //this is the error part

        new Lwjgl3Application(new MainFlappyBird(), config);
    }
}
```

[here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reT3J.png)

Comment: Please include your error or exception as text in the answer, not in an image. The error occurred because `Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration` has no field `width` or `height.` Check the `Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration` for these variables; maybe they are private, and you must use setters instead of directly assigning value to them.

Comment: this one ?

D:\mainflappybirds\desktop\src\com\mygdx\flappy\DesktopLauncher.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
  config.width = 480;
        ^
  symbol:   variable width
  location: variable config of type Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration

Comment: What does "missing F" have to do with your actual problem? Are you trying to be smart and use the letter "F" as a shorthand for the word "field", if so, don't do that.

Comment: [`Lwjgl3WindowConfiguration#setWindowedMode(int width, int height)`](https://www.mvndoc.com/c/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-backend-lwjgl3/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3WindowConfiguration.html#setWindowedMode-int-int-)

Answer (score 0):

Config is an object of type „Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration“ And this type does not have properties „width“ and „height“. That‘s why you can‘t assign values to this property, because it does not exist.

Comment: do you have advice what should i do?

Comment: I don‘t know what this application is. Is it a backend? A frontend? Is it Android? Spring? What is width and heigth and what are these values supposed to do?

Comment: i use intellij idea and it's for deskop. Width and height for game screen resolution

Comment: @DAXXKT *"do you have advice"* Maybe read some documentation?

Comment: The IDE should not have an impact. And you didn‘t answer any of my questions… please update your question with the answers to my question so that other people also know what exactly you‘re doing.